# Django : Factorize HTML code

Tags: django, django-templates

I am building a website about movies, actors etc... And I need your advices in order to factorize my templates.

Currently I have 5 templates :

- base.html : containing header menu, footer [located in the master templates folder]
- actors : display all the actors (extends base.html) [located in the templates folder from the application 'movie-library']
- actor : display one actor and all tbe movies he played in (extends base.html) [located in the templates folder from the application 'movie-library']
- movies : display all the movies (extends base.html) [located in the templates folder from the application 'movie-library']
- movie : display one movie (extends base.html) [located in the templates folder from the application 'movie-library']

So, in actor.html and movies.html it's the same HTML code to display one movie.
And in actors.html and movies.html I have the same HTML to display a pagination bar.

For example here is the code used to display a movie :

```
<div class="col s3 module">
  <div class="card movie-card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <a href="{% url 'movie' movie.id %}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ movie.photoshoot.folder }}/1.jpg" alt="{{ movie.title }} thumbnail"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">
        {{ movie.title }}
      </span>
      <p>
        <i class="material-icons blue-text accent-2-text">hd</i>
        {% if movie.movie is not None %}
          <i class="material-icons blue-text accent-2-text">local_movies</i>
        {% endif %}
        {% if movie.photos is not None %}
          <i class="material-icons blue-text accent-2-text">image</i>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="grey-text darken-1-text right">{{ movie.movie.duration }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I factorize those to piece of code ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use include tag for movies and custom tag for pagination